# Excel VBA function that cross references two data sets to come up with one solution

Tags: excel, vba, database, function

What I am trying to do is have a dynamic list of companies (I use data validation) that once chosen an impact number would be reported.

My data set consists of a list of companies and the associated country codes in which they operate (Company Table pic). The second data set has the country codes associated with the country name and the number of citizens in this country (Country Table pic).

A countries citizens are only impacted if 2 or more companies chosen are operating in that country.

Say I chose company 4 and company 6 in my drop down list (Company Selection pic). Since both these     companies operate in "AZ" and "BJ", I'm trying to get the output cell to populate with 1,079.

I want this to be possible with up to 20 company selections.

I wanted to do this with an index match but I couldnt understand how I could get it to return an array. My thinking is that for each company selection I would start to build up a unique array which would be populated with each companies country of operation. Then after that array has been built from all chosen company locations I would then assess that array and see if any country code occurs 2 or more times. If it does then I could return those country codes and use them to sumifs on the second database.

Attempt Code:

```
Function Impact(CompanySelection As Range, CompanyTable As Range, CountryTable As Range)
Dim CountryCodes As Object
Dim LookupCountries As Object
Dim Results As Object
Dim CImpact As Long

Dim cell As Variable

For Each cell In CompanySelection.Range

    If cell.Value = "" Then
    Exit For

    CountryCodes.Add Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(CompanyTable, Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(cell, CompanyTable, 0), 2)
    CountryCodes.Add Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(CompanyTable, Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(cell, CompanyTable, 0), 3)
    CountryCodes.Add Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(CompanyTable, Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(cell, CompanyTable, 0), 4)
    CountryCodes.Add Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(CompanyTable, Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(cell, CompanyTable, 0), 5)


Next

For each cell in CountryCodes 

count # of occurances of each unique country code


If code in CountryCodes occurs >=2 Then
    LookupCountries.Add Value

For Each cell In LookupCountries

    Result.Add Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(CountryTable, 
Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(cell, CountryTable, 2))

Next


For Each cell In Result
CImpact = CImpact + cell.Value
Next

Impact = CImpact
End Function
```

Company table

| Company | Country | Country | Country |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Company 1 | AO | BZ | BS |
| Company 2 | BW | AQ | AO |
| Company 3 | BA | BI |  |
| Company 4 | BR | AZ | BJ |
| Company 5 | AI |  |  |
| Company 6 | AZ | BJ | BS |

Country Table

| Country | Citizens |
| --- | --- |
| AO | 582 |
| AI | 536 |
| AQ | 350 |
| AZ | 732 |
| BA | 408 |
| BI | 826 |
| BJ | 347 |
| BR | 767 |
| BS | 336 |
| BW | 604 |
| BW | 601 |

Company Selection

| Company Selection |
| --- |
| Company 4 |
| Company 6 |
| ... |
| ... |
| ... |
| ... |

Output Cell

| Impacted Citizens = |
| --- |

Comment: Always post your code, even if does not give the results that you are looking for. That will tell us that you have tried and will help us to lead you in the right direction

Comment: The number of countries per company is three?  there is a limit? Why you need a VBA function? In a column on the right of companies (after countries) is easy to calculate the total citizens of countries using VLOOKUP on table of countries...

Comment: Oooo! "A countries citizens are only impacted if 2 or more companies chosen are operating in that country.".  I thing now understand...

Answer (score 1):

Solution using dictionary to count

```
Public Sub citizens()
    Dim ix As Integer, c As Integer, key As Variant
    Dim companyLocations As Range, locations As Range
    Set locations = Range("locations") 'Table with locations by company
    Dim dicCountries As Object
    Set dicCountries = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    For Each company In Range("companySelection") 'just the cells with the dropdown list
        ix = -1
        On Error Resume Next
        ix = WorksheetFunction.Match(company.Value, locations.Columns(1), 0)
        On Error GoTo 0
        
        If ix <> -1 Then
            Set companyLocations = locations.Rows(ix) 'Row that contains the the countries for that company
            For c = 2 To companyLocations.Columns.Count ' Check counties strating at column 2
                Key = Trim(companyLocations.Cells(1, c))
                If dicCountries.exists(Key) Then
                    dicCountries(Key) = dicCountries(Key) + 1
                Else
                    dicCountries(Key) = 1
                End If
            Next c
        End If
    Next company
    Dim citizens  As Long
    citizens = 0
    For Each Key In dicCountries.keys()
        If dicCountries(Key) > 1 Then
            citizens = citizens + WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Key, Range("countryTable"), 2, False)
        End If
    Next Key
    Range("e36").Value = citizens 'whatever cell you want the result
End Sub

``
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the ix portion of the code.

Comment: will add comments to the code for you to follow

Answer (score 0):

[image: modified... to sum only if country exist twise]

I think now that it is correct. a) Concat countries per company, b) concat countries of selected companies, c) check every country if exists twise in (b), d) set citizens in main table only if country exists twise. But the VBA is more flexible!

Comment: For your example (since I can't attach pictures yet) the sum for columns D24:D43 should be 582. This is because the country code "AO" is the only one that occurs twice or more with the selection of companies.

I am working on a VBA code and will post my attempt once completed

Answer (score 0):

I used wrbp's solution and made a few changes for it to suit my use case.

```
Public Sub citizens()
Dim companyLocations As Range, locations As Range
Set locations = Application.Workbooks("Test File.xlsm").Worksheets("Test").Range("A5:F45") 'Table with locations by company
Dim dicCountries As Object
Set dicCountries = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

Dim cell As Range
Dim i As Long

'For Each cell In locations.Columns(1).Cells
    'Debug.Print cell.Value
'Next cell

For Each company In Application.Workbooks("Macro Worksheet.xlsm").Worksheets("Test").Range("L5:L24").Cells 'just the cells with the dropdown list
    ix = -1

    On Error Resume Next
    'Debug.Print company
    ix = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(company.Value, locations.Columns(1).Cells, 0)
    Debug.Print ix
    On Error GoTo 0
       
    If ix <> -1 Then
        Set companyLocations = locations.Rows(ix)
        For c = 2 To companyLocations.Columns.Count
            key = Trim(companyLocations.Cells(1, c))
            
            If key = "" Then
                Exit For
            
            ElseIf dicCountries.exists(key) Then
                dicCountries(key) = dicCountries(key) + 1
            Else
                dicCountries(key) = 1
            End If
        Next c
    End If

    
Next company
For Each key In dicCountries.Keys
   Debug.Print key, dicCountries(key)
Next key



Dim citizens  As Long
citizens = 0
For Each key In dicCountries.Keys()
    If dicCountries(key) > 1 Then
        Debug.Print WorksheetFunction.VLookup(key, Application.Workbooks("Macro Worksheet.xlsm").Worksheets("Test").Range("B49:C85"), 2, False)
        citizens = citizens + WorksheetFunction.VLookup(key, Application.Workbooks("Macro Worksheet.xlsm").Worksheets("Test").Range("B49:C85"), 2, False)
    End If
    
Next key
Range("H1").Value = citizens 'whatever cell you want the result
End Sub
```